# How to select the edges that have bevel weight only?

Tags: vertex-weights

Is there a way to select the edges that have bevel weight?  I've seen how to select by similar angles, sharpness, yet I have not seen a bevel weight selection option.

Comment: Do you mean weighted by the _Weighted Normal_ modifier? As far as I know it works on vertices and you can restrict it to vertex groups, so you only have to select the vertices in the group...? Or do you mean edges with a _Bevel Weight_?

Comment: Yes, Bevel Weight. Sorry, my mistake I wrote "weighted normal edges" I was talking about Bevel weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked in the comment if you mean *Bevel* instead of *Normal* weight because bevel is quite easy.

If you have edges with different bevel weights, e.g. 1.0, 0.5 and 0.25 while some have 0, and you want to select all with some bevel weight, whatever high it may be, you could try to select one  with i.e. 0.5 and then use *Select* > *Select Similar* > *Bevel*.

Of course this won't work, because only the edges with a bevel weight of exactly 0.5 will be selected.

To select all edges with a bevel weight > 0, select one which has 0, then *Select* > *Select Similar* > *Bevel*. Now all edges with bevel weight = 0 are selected. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to invert the selection. Now all edges with a weight above 0 are selected.

Comment: That's very well explained. It worked pretty fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's there, alright.. (Edge Mode), <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> *Select Similar* > *Bevel*. You can set the epsilon in the <kbd>F9</kbd> 'Adjust Last Operation' panel.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I selected a clean edge, then selected similar > bevel, then invert selection, pretty nice.